# Is there a R function to print & export column names to excel?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Im trying to append survey data sets of different versions of the survey to create a master file. 
But, the different survey versions do not have uniform number of columns across. ( E.g : V1 - 10k vars, V2- 20k vars). I would like to see what are the 10k missing vars in V1 in comparison to V2.

Is there a R function which could print & export the colnames of the data to excel?

Thank you.

Comment: I use the `openxlsx` package to read from and write to excel (.xlsx) files (one advantage of `openxlsx` is that it does not have JAVA as a dependency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can make a dataframe of column names:

```
df1_names <- as.data.frame(colnames(df1))
df2_names <- as.data.frame(colnames(df2))
```

If you want your column names across rows (wide instead of long), you can transpose them:

```
df1_names <- as.data.frame(t(df1_names))
df2_names <- as.data.frame(t(df2_names))
```

Then, using the `xlsx` package, you can write to Excel:

```
write.xlsx(df1_names, filename)
write.xlsx(df2_names, filename)
```

Comment: I think you will need to **transpose** the column names within the excel file to adjust from tall to wide, but this works great.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this is really helpful!

Comment: Happy to help, Nelson! If this worked to solve your question, please feel free to click on the checkmark to indicate that everything is resolved.